# What determines the minimum size of items on the screen?

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution

Referring to the image below: What determines the minimum value for the "size of text, apps and other items"? What is 100%, and how is it possible to go below this? Is this solely dependent on the screen resolution, or is it affected by other specifications?

[image: Settings]

Comment: 100% = 96dpi so the normal setting that Windows had for years